cor.test "not enough finite observations" in correlation between 2 dataframes
when I perform correlation between 2 datasets using cor.test I obtain the error: "not enough finite observations". The first dataframe is gene expression in patients, the second is proteomic data in the same patients. The two final dataframes have same number of rows (patients) and columns (same genes in the same order).
How to analyze data with NA value?
My code is:
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(purrr)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

FPKM <- read.table("CPTAC_clinical_mRNA_fpkm_data.txt", sep = '\t', header = T)
proteome <- read.table("CPTAC_clinical_proteome_data.txt", sep = '\t', header = T)
colnames(proteome)[1] <- "PATIENT_ID"
proteome <- subset( proteome, select = -c( 2 : 9 ))  #remove all columns between 2-9
    
FPKM <- FPKM[,colSums(!is.na(FPKM))>=3] 
proteome <- proteome[,colSums(!is.na(proteome))>=3]

rownames(proteome) <- proteome[,1]
proteome[,1] <- NULL

rownames(FPKM) <- FPKM[,1]
FPKM[,1] <- NULL

names_proteome <- names(proteome)
names_FPKM <- names(FPKM) 
names_intersect <- intersect(names_proteome,names_FPKM)

# subset dataframe based on intersected colnames
FPKM_subset <- FPKM[, names_intersect]
proteome_subset <- proteome[, names_intersect]

cor_mat <- cor(FPKM_subset, proteome_subset)
corrplot::corrplot(cor_mat)

correlations <- list()    #empty list
for(name in names_intersect){       #correlation between columns with same names in both dataframes
  correlations[[name]] <- cor.test(FPKM_subset[, name], proteome_subset[, name], method = "pearson") 
}

# transform list of correlation in dataframe
library(broom)
library(purrr)
correlations_df <- map_dfr(correlations, tidy, .id = 'id')

A MRE to reproduce error is:
FPKM_subset <- data.frame(APC = c(0.4125,0.5008,0.6385,0.0824,1.2417,1.5122,2.1504,1.9855,1.8962,1.2911,1.8109,1.9295,1.2686,1.6429,1.9249,1.3935,1.5063,1.7209,0.6211,0.2128,1.5463,1.8345,2.2006,1.9024,-1.5135,2.6089,1.6247,1.9672,2.009,2.6702,1.4941,0.675,2.1981,2.444,1.926,1.6224,1.8575,1.0613,1.2514,1.6435,0.7361,2.3549,1.6633,2.2753,2.1009,-0.9891,0.8806,3.2166,2.1427,2.2832,2.0566,2.0884,1.954,1.9872,2.3231,2.4595,1.9547,2.1698,2.1434,1.4817,0.9033,1.9107,1.8307,2.1462,2.3176,1.6017,1.4789,2.5415,1.9214,1.8895,2.3539,1.9381,2.4413,2.0123,2.0585,1.9324,1.9599,1.7519,2.0757,1.8758,2.2422,2.3885,2.005,1.8084,1.9178,2.2548,1.8803,1.7217,2.5567,2.0467,1.5637,2.024,1.9051,2.7917,1.3717,1.3187,1.4722,1.8799,1.8462,2.0979,2.0128,1.7247,1.7548,2.0862,1.9086,1.9866,2.1614,1.8866,1.9273,1.8266,1.8701,1.3227,1.6252,2.2721,2.4298,2.2016,2.8544,0.06,0.8422,2.3475,2.032,1.71), APC2 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.1715,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-0.2037,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,7.7077,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

proteome_subset <- data.frame(APC = c(-4.7200866,-1.01,-1.3759449,-1.2026746,0.336,0.1112911,0.54192644,-0.732,-1.0439774,0.833,0.09310844,-0.3793738,-0.52924716,-0.804,-0.256,-0.21412534,-0.771,1.408545,-1.1243287,-1.5875859,-2.17,0.388,0.16744348,0.538,0.187,0.659,0.62909627,1.72,-0.474,-0.4928818,0.272,1.01,-0.263,2.041329,0.609,-1.0626949,0.030538633,-2.0757105,-1.25,0.4010107,0.46638808,-0.737,0.873,-0.04393013,-0.8725789,0.677,-0.035106182,1.7668507,-0.24902003,0.685115,0.5964744,1.43,-0.334,-0.291,0.503,1.58,1.5890348,0.517,1.3073368,0.293,-2.35,-0.19621004,1.3216423,-0.11893366,0.6236148,-0.648,-1.3092306,0.5328351,-0.567,0.048186526,-0.75,0.256,1.1415536,-0.099,0.15447497,-0.323,-0.56026465,0.623,0.635,1.08,-2.5461874,-0.17281322,0.0987,0.606368,1.1415536,1.6,0.83204705,-0.291,0.359,0.7856544,-1.25,-0.13029784,-0.19233285,0.5968755,0.5947364,0.477,-2.04,0.0336,0.13976839,-0.56761795,-0.33913124,-0.19928505,-0.502,0.8101208,-0.31827462,1.16,-0.448,0.114,-0.23190692,-0.002885404,0.6940726,0.752,-1.78,1.2194984,1.4152298,-0.28311256,0.842,-0.6739064,0.32547235,0.0358,-0.603,0.301), APC2 = c(0.16873093,-1.23,0.32215953,-0.2863737,-0.645,-0.5431744,-0.504274,NA,NA,-0.533,0.8326272,-2.340403,-0.74051726,NA,NA,NA,-0.404,-0.13658026,NA,0.3103766,-1.57,1.77,NA,NA,0.408,-0.18,-0.28344887,NA,NA,-1.8067039,-0.588,-0.359,-0.211,NA,NA,-1.8787385,NA,NA,NA,0.2556404,-0.37528875,NA,0.549,0.38399893,1.1665599,1.89,NA,-0.81071335,NA,NA,3.7133827,1.05,NA,NA,0.824,-0.138,-0.061996922,NA,0.29763266,0.0743,-0.0362,0.99336785,0.4681089,NA,-0.026522825,NA,NA,-0.13645492,NA,NA,NA,-0.163,NA,-1.03,NA,-0.552,0.5728598,NA,0.245,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.899,NA,0.334,NA,0.2048318,NA,NA,NA,NA,-0.028946262,0.00406,-1.04,NA,1.3385822,0.64034003,0.38019663,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.574573,NA,NA,NA,-0.118,NA,-2.4088862,-0.5600549,0.151,-0.9340162,-0.39108288,2.24,NA,NA))

Thanks

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

As @MrFlick said it's hard to help without a reproducible example, especially not seeing the data. That error comes up when there are less than 3 complete cases I think so my guess would be that while each column you selected has at least 3 non NA values they are not matched and so you have fewer complete cases

Dear @MrFlick I added a MRE to my post to reproduce the error

Dear @andrewb I added a MRE to my post to reproduce the error

From the sample data, you can't run a correlation with the APC2 data because there are only three rows in FPMK where APC2 is not NA and of those three, only two rows in proteome are not NA. That's simply not enough data to perform a cor.test
